# BigQuery FIRST_VALUE and IGNORE_NULLS - why it works this way?

Tags: google-bigquery

My problem is to find first value from column over some window, here is example data with query:

```
WITH finishers AS
 (SELECT 'Bob' as name,
  TIMESTAMP '2016-10-18 2:51:45' as finish_time,
  'F30-34' as division
  UNION ALL SELECT NULL, TIMESTAMP '2016-10-18 2:54:11', 'F35-39'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Mary', TIMESTAMP '2016-10-18 2:59:01', 'F35-39'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'John', TIMESTAMP '2016-10-18 3:01:17', 'F35-39')
SELECT *,
 FIRST_VALUE (name IGNORE NULLS) OVER(PARTITION BY division ORDER BY finish_time) AS fastest_in_division
FROM finishers
ORDER by division
```

The outcome is:

```
Row name    finish_time             division  fastest_in_division    
1   Bob     2016-10-18 02:51:45 UTC F30-34    Bob    
2   null    2016-10-18 02:54:11 UTC F35-39    **null**   
3   Mary    2016-10-18 02:59:01 UTC F35-39    Mary   
4   John    2016-10-18 03:01:17 UTC F35-39    Mary
```

While my expectation is:

```
Row name    finish_time             division  fastest_in_division    
1   Bob     2016-10-18 02:51:45 UTC F30-34    Bob    
2   null    2016-10-18 02:54:11 UTC F35-39    **Mary**
3   Mary    2016-10-18 02:59:01 UTC F35-39    Mary   
4   John    2016-10-18 03:01:17 UTC F35-39    Mary
```

It seems that IGNORE_NULLS skips rows when 'name' is null AND is first in order - then it returns 'null' instead of 'Mary', as in other rows. Is there any way to bypass this behaviour?

Comment: In ascending order, the row with NULL comes first, so there is no non-NULL name in the window. Maybe you meant to use ORDER BY with DESC?

Comment: I thought that the window is 'division' and there are other non-NULL names in it but maybe I'm wrong. ORDER BY DESC would have same problem if the row with NULL would come last so that won't help me alas.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To achive your expectation the query should look like below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH finishers AS  (
  SELECT 'Bob' AS name, TIMESTAMP '2016-10-18 2:51:45' AS finish_time, 'F30-34' AS division UNION ALL 
  SELECT NULL, TIMESTAMP '2016-10-18 2:54:11', 'F35-39' UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'Mary', TIMESTAMP '2016-10-18 2:59:01', 'F35-39' UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'John', TIMESTAMP '2016-10-18 3:01:17', 'F35-39'
)
SELECT *,
  FIRST_VALUE (name IGNORE NULLS) 
    OVER(PARTITION BY division ORDER BY finish_time 
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
  ) AS fastest_in_division
FROM finishers
ORDER BY finish_time, division
```

with result as you expected:

```sql
Row name    finish_time             division    fastest_in_division  
1   Bob     2016-10-18 02:51:45 UTC F30-34      Bob  
2   null    2016-10-18 02:54:11 UTC F35-39      Mary     
3   Mary    2016-10-18 02:59:01 UTC F35-39      Mary     
4   John    2016-10-18 03:01:17 UTC F35-39      Mary
```

The problem you had because by default - the scope of OVER with ORDER BY is BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW in respective partition based on given order, but looks like you expect the whole partition to be involved

Comment: [spam] Accepted :)

Comment: This makes a massive difference to the functionality of the function, I wish it was explained better in the documentation. Thanks for answering! (shedding light even 5+ years later)